# Find Multiple Criteria move active cell up 1

Tags: excel, vba

How do I modify this to search for numerous different phrases instead of just one?

```
Rows(4).Find("Part Number", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(-1) = "CPN"
Cells.Find(What:="CPN").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Do something
```

Instead of searching for just "Part Number", I'd like to search for either, "CPN", "Part Number", "Part Num", "P/N", or "Mfg PN"
Only one of the above phrases will ever be found.

This code searches for "Part Number" in row 4, in the cell above the found criteria "CPN" is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look for all of them:

```
On error resume next
    Rows(4).Find("Part Number", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(-1) = "CPN"
    Rows(4).Find("CPN", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(-1) = "CPN"
    Rows(4).Find("Part Num", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(-1) = "CPN"
    Rows(4).Find("P/N", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(-1) = "CPN"
    Rows(4).Find("Mfg PN", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(-1) = "CPN"
On error goto 0
Cells.Find(What:="CPN").Offset(-1, 0).Select
Do something
```

Comment: Didn't think about pasting the same line over and over again, but that does work..

Comment: You could make it a little prettier... put all the terms into an array: `MyArray = array("
term1", "term2"...` then looping through the array... or maybe using a dictionary... Or maybe identify which one is there first. IDK. but if you're not doing it for a client 5 lines isn't too ugly.